# $\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \omega(n/d)=0$ for composite numbers. How?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I need some help with the last(?) step in a proof and I'm not sure how I should proceed... $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors. We see that for $n$ prime,
$$\sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d)\omega(n/d )=\mu(1)\omega(n)+\mu(n)\omega(1)=1.$$
But for $n$ composite I'm at a loss. My idea is to somehow show that if $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$, then the terms in the following sum will cancel each other, like this:
$$\sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d)\omega(n/d )=\omega(n)-\sum\omega\left(\frac{n}{p_i}\right)+\sum\omega\left(\frac{n}{p_ip_j}\right)+\ldots+\sum\omega\left(\frac{n}{p_1p_2\ldots p_k}\right)(-1)^{k},$$
where we just skip the divisors with exponent $a_i>1$ since $\mu$ would cancel them. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is this nonsense?

**Added** (clarification):

For $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$,
$$\sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d)\omega \left( \frac{n}{d} \right)=\omega(n)+\underbrace{\mu(p_1) \omega(n/p_1)+ \ldots+\mu(p_k) \omega(n/p_k)}_{-\sum\omega\left(\frac{n}{p_i}\right)}+ \ldots + \mu(p_1 \ldots p_k) \omega\left(\frac{n}{p_1\ldots p_k}\right)$$
where $\mu(p_i)=-1$ and $\mu(p_1 \ldots p_k)=(-1)^{k}$. So we don't sum terms with square factors since they would be 0 in any case.

Comment: Your cancellation method gives, via the Binomial theorem and its derivative, $$\sum_{i=0}^k (k-i)(-1)^i {k \choose i} = k(1+(-1))^k - k(-1)(1+(-1))^{k-1}.$$ This formally evaluates to $1$ if $\omega(n)=k=1$ and $0$ if $k>1$. I'm not sure how you did the cancellation in the first place though...

Comment: @anon: Thanks! I added a clarification to the post. Could you explain how to get from my cancellation to your formula? I was trying to do something like it, but I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: I've updated my post. The reasoning process required was longer than I originally anticipated (for your direction) but my idea still applies at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $P_i(k)$, $i=1,2,...\binom{\omega(n)}{k}$, be an enumeration of the products of $k$ of the prime factors of $n$, and $\nu(n)$ be the number of prime factors of $n$ with exponent $1$.  Then $\binom{\nu(n)}{j}$ is the number of ways to choose $j$ primes with exponent $1$, and $\binom{\omega(n)-\nu(n)}{k-j}$ is the number of ways to choose $k-j$ primes with exponent greater than $1$.  The primes with exponent $1$ in $n$ appearing in $P_i(k)$ decreases $\omega(\frac{n}{P_i(k)})$ to $\omega(n)-j$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\binom{\omega(n)}{k}}\omega(\frac{n}{P_i(k)})
&=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{\nu(n)}{j}\binom{\omega(n)\!-\!\nu(n)}{k\!-\!j}(\omega(n)\!-\!j)\\
&=\binom{\omega(n)}{k}\omega(n)-\sum_{j=0}^k \;j\binom{\nu(n)}{j}\binom{\omega(n)\!-\!\nu(n)}{k\!-\!j}\\
&=\binom{\omega(n)}{k}\omega(n)-\sum_{j=1}^k \;\nu(n)\binom{\nu(n)\!-\!1}{j\!-\!1}\binom{\omega(n)\!-\!\nu(n)}{k\!-\!j}\\
&=\binom{\omega(n)}{k}\omega(n)-\binom{\omega(n)\!-\!1}{k\!-\!1}\nu(n)
\end{align}
$$
Because $\sum_k \binom{\omega(n)}{k}\;(-1)^k = 1$ when $\omega(n)=0$ and $0$ otherwise, we get that your alternating sum is $0$ when $\omega(n)=0$ and $\nu(n)$ when $\omega(n)=1$ and $0$ when $\omega(n)>1$.

$\omega(n)=0$ only when $n=1$. $\omega(n)=1$ and $\nu(n)=1$ only when $n$ is prime.  When $n$ is composite, either $\omega(n)>1$ or $\nu(n)=0$.  This should handle all cases.

Comment: Sorry for asking a stupid question, but what is $k$ in the first sum?

Comment: And btw, $C(n,k)$, is that the same as $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: @Carolus: $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ whose product is $P_i(k)$.  If $n = 2^3*3*5^2*7$, then $P_i(2)$ ranges over $2*3$, $2*5$, $2*7$, $3*5$, $3*7$, and $5*7$.  Thus, $\mu(P_i(k))=(-1)^k$.

Comment: @Carolus: yes, $C(n,k)=\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 8):

**Updated with heavy clarifications / elaborations**.

Let $f(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \omega(n/d)$. Then, by [Möbius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), we have $\omega(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)$. Let $g(m)$ be the arithmetic function which evaluates to $1$ for prime $m$ and $0$ for composite $m$. Then we can write the difference function $h(n) = \sum_{d|n} [f(d)-g(d)]=0$, and use Möbius inversion again in the reverse direction to get $f(n)-g(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) h(n/d) = 0$, which proves the original hypothesis.

(Originally I believed some form of induction was best suited to finish off this proof, but discovered that that wasn't going to work while second inversion would.)

---

In order to go from your post-cancellation sum to the desired conclusion, we will split $n$'s prime factorization into two components, a "$\mu$" part and a "$\mu$-free" part, as $n=ab$, where $a=q_1\cdots q_k$ and $b= p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_l^{e_l}$ with exponents $e_i\ge 2$. Also write $b'=p_1\cdots p_l$. For divisors $d|n$, we write $d=d_1d_2$, where $d_1|a$ and $d_2|b$. Then $\mu(d)\ne 0$ if and only if $d_2|b'$, so we can write the sum as

$$\sum_{d_1|a}\, \sum_{d_2|b'} \mu(d_1d_2) \omega\left(\frac{ab}{d_1d_2}\right) = \left(\sum_{d_1|a} \mu(d_1)[l +\omega(a/d_1)]\right)\left( \sum_{d_2|b'} \mu(d_2)\right)$$

(Note that $\omega(b/d_2)=l$ regardless of $d_2$ because of the exponents in $b$'s prime factorization, and we use separations $\omega(xy) = \omega(x)+\omega(y)$, $\mu(xy)=\mu(x)\mu(y)$ when $\gcd(x,y)=1$.) The righthand factor above is $0$ except when $b'=1$, i.e. when $n=a$. In that case we can further reduce the sum to

$$\sum_{d_1|a} \mu(d_1)\omega(a/d_1).$$

Now my original reasoning kicks in, by letting $Q$ be the set of prime factors of $a$, and then following the explicit deduction in user10676 answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this... I understand the first part, up to induction... I don't get the _test_ -part.

Comment: You write: "Let $g(m)$ be the arithmetic function which evaluates to 1 for prime $m$ and 0 for composite $m$" - But this is the very definition of $f(n)$ which we are trying to prove, isn't it?

Comment: @Carolus: Precisely. Since $\sum_{d|n} g(d)=\omega(n)$ just like with $f(d)$, we can write $\sum f-g = 0$ and then use Mobius inversion to get $f-g=0$ which proves they are one in the same.

Comment: Of course... I'm obviously too tired to keep going with this today! I'll read it tomorrow again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to complete what you have started, as suggested by Anon.

Let $P$ be the set of primes factors of $n$. Then one have
$$ \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \omega(n/d) = \sum_{I \subset P} (-1)^{|I|} (|P|-|I|) $$
Then split the sum according to the cardinal of $I$:
$$ \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \omega(n/d) = \sum_{k =0}^{|P|} \binom{|P|}{k} (-1)^{k} (|P|-k) $$
Conclude with the facts that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{|P|}  \binom{|P|}{k} (-1)^{k} = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } |P| \geq 1 \\ 1, & \text{if } |P|=0 \end{cases} $$
and
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{|P|}  \binom{|P|}{k} k (-1)^{k} = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } |P| \geq 2 \\ -1, & \text{if } |P|=1 \\ 0, & \text{if } |P|=0. \end{cases} $$
(For the last one, notice that $k\binom{N}{k} = N\binom{N-1}{k-1}$)

Comment: This reasoning only works when the exponents in $n$'s prime factorization are all $1$. In my answer I reduce the problem down to just such a case and then outsource to your explication, so please keep it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Define $k(n)$ to be $1$ if $n$ is prime and $0$ if n is composite, then

$$\sum_{d\mid n}k(d)=\sum_{p\mid n}k(p)=\sum_{p\mid n}1=\omega(n)$$

And by the Möbius inversion formula,

$$k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\omega(\frac{n}{d})$$

As required